# How to reuse the same C code but with different operators

Tags: c, operators, semantics, code-reuse

I am building a library in C and one of the functions that is part of the library is something like:

```
void myFunction(double *inPtr, double start, double step, double *outPtr, int N, t_shape shape)
{
    int i;

    switch (shape) {

        default:
        case ShapeLinear:
            /* more stuff going on */
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                *(outPtr++) = *(inPtr++) * start;
                start += step;
            }
            /* more stuff going on */
            break;

        case ShapeExponential:
            /* more stuff going on */
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                *(outPtr++) = *(inPtr++) * start;
                start *= step;
            }
            /* more stuff going on */
            break;

        case ShapeSquared:
            /* more stuff going on */
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                *(outPtr++) = *(inPtr++) * start * start;
                start += step;
            }
            /* more stuff going on */
            break;

        case ShapeCubed:
            /* more stuff going on */
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                *(outPtr++) = *(inPtr++) * start * start * start;
                start += step;
            }
            /* more stuff going on */
            break;
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version just for the purpose of demonstration.
The actual function in the library has more cases and each case is longer and more complex.

Now I would like to create another version of exactly the same function with the only difference that instead of just **assigning** a value to outPtr, I would like to **add and assign** it.

```
void myFunctionAdd(double *inPtr, double start, double step, double *outPtr, int N, t_shape shape)
{
    int i;

    switch (shape) {

        default:
        case ShapeLinear:
            /* more stuff going on */
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                *(outPtr++) += *(inPtr++) * start;
                start += step;
            }
            /* more stuff going on */
            break;

        case ShapeExponential:
            /* more stuff going on */
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                *(outPtr++) += *(inPtr++) * start;
                start *= step;
            }
            /* more stuff going on */
            break;

        case ShapeSquared:
            /* more stuff going on */
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                *(outPtr++) += *(inPtr++) * start * start;
                start += step;
            }
            /* more stuff going on */
            break;

        case ShapeCubed:
            /* more stuff going on */
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                *(outPtr++) += *(inPtr++) * start * start * start;
                start += step;
            }
            /* more stuff going on */
            break;
    }
}
```

As I said, the real function I am working on is longer and more complex so having to rewrite the same code twice is really something I wouldn’t want to do.
It would be bad programming practice and more difficult to maintain.

Is there a C programming technique to deal with this issue?
Could blocks (closures) be useful in this situation?
Do I need to refactor the code somehow?
How would you tackle the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the classic c solution is to pass in a function that gets called to do what you want to vary. This depends however on the basic shape of the operation being the same

ie

```
typedef int (*func_ptr)(int,int); 
myFunction(....... func_ptr do_what)
{
int i;

switch (shape) {

    default:
    case ShapeLinear:
        /* more stuff going on */
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            *(outPtr++) = func_ptr(*(inptr++), outPtr);
            start += step;
        }
        /* more stuff going on */
        break;
}

int assign(int a, int b)
{
return a;
}

int add_assign(int a, int b)
{
return a + b;
}
```

then call

```
 myFunction(......assign);
```

or

```
myfunction(......add_assign);
```

this feels a bit forced in your case tho since we have to pass in the old value of outPtr

Comment: Thank you, however I don't see how I won't have to duplicate my code using your strategy. I will still have to write two do_what() functions. One will add outPtr to the result and the other won't. It is true that I could put a conditional statement, however it will have an impact on efficiency. On top of that I am not crazy about calling a function in a loop, unless it is strictly necessary.

Comment: yes but the do_what funtion is only one line - see edit

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do looks more or less like a map operation. I would instead define a function *Map* and call it with different input functions. Below is a compilable example. Hopefully you can expand upon it to fit your problem.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN(array) (sizeof (array) / sizeof (array)[0])

typedef double (*Function)(double x);

static void Map(Function f, const double arr[], int arrLen, double result[], int resultLen)
{
    int i;

    assert(resultLen >= arrLen);

    for (i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
        result[i] = f(arr[i]);
    }
}


static double Square(double x)
{
    return x * x;
}


int main(void)
{
    double arr[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
    double result[LEN(arr)];
    int i;

    Map(Square, arr, LEN(arr), result, LEN(result));

    for (i = 0; i < LEN(result); i++) {
        printf("%f\n", result[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of operators use a function that takes some constant that defines what the function does. That way you can structure a lot of your logic in the same manner and only vary the parameter to the function to decide what the actual operation/s is/are within the function.

The function or functions can be a series of overloads as well to help you no repeat too much of your code. Note that you will have to refactor your code to pass in the target of assignments (or non-assignments).

```
// rough, simplistic, pseudo-codish example:

public void MyOperatorFunc(int opType, int var1, int var2, int* output) {
      if (opType == 1 ) {
          output = output + var1 + var2; 
      }
      else if (opType == 2) {
          output = var1 + var2;
      }
      // ...
 }
```

Note that with a solution like this the only "shape" that becomes important is your count of operands.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, however I don't see how this will help me not to repeat my code. The same code that is called when opType == 1 will be called when opType == 2. The only things different when opType == 2 is the assignment operator. But this means that I still need to duplicate my code.